# How to auto restart a Qt application when it crashes, within the same program?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, process, restart

Is there any relatively "standard" design to auto restart a Qt application program, when it crashes abnormally?

Specific to Windows, do I have to use any windows service?
Or if I have to write another program separately, then how to do that?

Comment: You can make your application as windows service and set "Recovery" property (when service fails) to "Restart the service". To create windows service on Qt you can try this project: https://github.com/qtproject/qt-solutions/tree/master/qtservice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how you might do it using a single application that can act either as a monitor or as business logic. It's akin to Jon Harper's answer, except in code, not prose :)

#### Of Note

1. The monitor should not instantiate a `QApplication` nor `QGuiApplication`: it has no UI. Otherwise, redundant running process indicators will appear on some platforms (i.e. OS X, Win 10).
2. The monitor/business logic selection is achieved via setting an environment variable in the called process.
3. Passing the monitor/business logic selection via command line arguments is problematic, as the command line switch would need to be filtered out -- doing that portably without running into corner cases is tricky.
4. The monitor process forwards the console I/O of the business logic process, as well as the return code.

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/appmonitor-37524491
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <cstdlib>
#if defined(Q_OS_WIN32)
#include <windows.h>
#else
static void DebugBreak() { abort(); }
#endif

static int businessLogicMain(int &argc, char **argv) {
   QApplication app{argc, argv};
   qDebug() << __FUNCTION__ << app.arguments();
   QWidget w;
   QHBoxLayout layout{&w};
   QPushButton crash{"Crash"};  // purposefully crash for testing
   QPushButton quit{"Quit"};    // graceful exit, which doesn't need restart
   layout.addWidget(&crash);
   layout.addWidget(&quit);
   w.show();

   QObject::connect(&crash, &QPushButton::clicked, DebugBreak);
   QObject::connect(&quit, &QPushButton::clicked, &QCoreApplication::quit);
   return app.exec();
}

static char const kRunLogic[] = "run__business__logic";
static char const kRunLogicValue[] = "run__business__logic";

#if defined(Q_OS_WIN32)
static QString getWindowsCommandLineArguments() {
   const wchar_t *args = GetCommandLine();
   bool oddBackslash = false, quoted = false, whitespace = false;
   // skip the executable name according to Windows command line parsing rules
   while (auto c = *args) {
      if (c == L'\\')
         oddBackslash ^= 1;
      else if (c == L'"')
         quoted ^= !oddBackslash;
      else if (c == L' ' || c == L'\t')
         whitespace = !quoted;
      else if (whitespace)
         break;
      else
         oddBackslash = false;
      args++;
   }
   return QString::fromRawData(reinterpret_cast<const QChar*>(args), lstrlen(args));
}
#endif

static int monitorMain(int &argc, char **argv) {
#if !defined(Q_OS_WIN32)
   QStringList args;
   args.reserve(argc-1);
   for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
     args << QString::fromLocal8Bit(argv[i]);
#endif
   QCoreApplication app{argc, argv};
   QProcess proc;
   auto onFinished = [&](int retcode, QProcess::ExitStatus status) {
      qDebug() << status;
      if (status == QProcess::CrashExit)
         proc.start();      // restart the app if the app crashed
      else
         app.exit(retcode); // no restart required
   };
   QObject::connect(&proc, QOverload<int, QProcess::ExitStatus>::of(&QProcess::finished), onFinished);

   auto env = QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment();
   env.insert(kRunLogic, kRunLogicValue);
   proc.setProgram(app.applicationFilePath()); // logic and monitor are the same executable
#if defined(Q_OS_WIN32)
   SetErrorMode(SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX);        // disable Windows error reporting
   proc.setNativeArguments(getWindowsCommandLineArguments()); // pass command line arguments natively
   env.insert("QT_LOGGING_TO_CONSOLE", "1");   // ensure that the debug output gets passed along
#else
   proc.setArguments(args);
#endif
   proc.setProcessEnvironment(env);
   proc.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::ForwardedChannels);
   proc.start();
   return app.exec();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   if (qgetenv(kRunLogic) != kRunLogicValue)
      return monitorMain(argc, argv);
   else
      return qunsetenv(kRunLogic), businessLogicMain(argc, argv);
}
```

Comment: I'd give an extra +1 for the "code, not prose" if I could. :-)

Answer (score 3):

If an application crashes, it's done.

Your monitor idea is a good one, and can be achieved using [`QProcess`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html). Use the "monitor" to bootstrap your actual application. To do this, implement a monitoring object with a `QProcess` member. In pseudocode:

```
 class MonitorObject : public QObject
 {
     ...
 public Q_SLOTS:
     void onStarted();
     void onFinished(int, QProcess::ExitStatus);
     ...
 private:
     QProcess m_process;
 }
```

Then in `main`:

- Create a `QCoreApplication` and a monitoring object on the stack.
- Send a queued signal to your monitor object so it knows when the main event loop starts. You can achieve this using [`QMetaObject::invoke`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod) with a `Qt::QueuedConnection`:

  ```
  int main(...)
  {
      QCoreApplication app;
      MonitorObject monitor;

      ... // other initialization code here

      QMetaObject::invoke(&monitor, "onStarted", Qt::QueuedConnection);
      return app.exec();
  }
  ```

And in your `MonitorObject`:

- Connect `QProcess`'s `finished` signal to `onFinished`.
- When `MonitorObject::onStarted` is called, start the process.
- When the `QProcess::finished` signal fires, either restart the offending program or exit, depending on the `exitCode` argument in the emitted signal.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any standard Qt method for restarting apps when they crash. But there is a nice class available which makes writing a supervisor/monitor class very easy. It is called QProcess.

You can start the process like this:

```
monitorClass::startProcess(QString commandLine) // e.g. "c:\mytestapp.exe param1 param2"
{
    mp_Process = new QProcess(this);
    mp_Process->start(commandLine);
    mp_Process->waitForStarted();

    // Start a timer
    mp_Timer->start(1000);
}
```

Then when the timer expires (every second - or whatever)

```
void monitorClass::TimerExpired(void)
{
    switch (mp_Process->state())
    {
        default:
        case QProcess::NotRunning:
        {
            qDebug("Process has stopped un-expectedly\n");

            // Tell the supervisor that the process has terminated
            // restart the process
            startProcess("c:\mytestapp.exe param1 param2"); // just an example
            break;
        }
        case QProcess::Starting:
        case QProcess::Running:
        {
            qDebug("Process is running ok\n");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**

This is really pseudo code, its not a compilable example - it is just to show you roughly the how easy it is to do this with QProcess...