# How to pass command line arguments verbatim to a QProcess?

Tags: qt, command-line-arguments, qprocess

How does one pass the command line arguments of the current process to a `QProcess`, ideally avoiding any conversions? I.e. whatever "junk" was passed to the current process is supposed to be passed to the sub-process, without the fallout of conversions between `char*`, `wchar_t` and `QString`.

The question is motivated by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37530784/1329652).

Answer (score 2):

### Windows

The native command line returned by `GetCommandLine()` is a `wchar_t` array that begins with the executable name/path. `QProcess` has the `setNativeArguments` method available on Windows, and that method can be used to append the arguments part of the command line. The main job is then to [parse the command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/parsing-cpp-command-line-arguments) to find the beginning of the arguments:

```
QString getWindowsCommandLineArguments() {
   const wchar_t *args = GetCommandLine();
   bool oddBackslash = false, quoted = false, whitespace = false;
   // skip the executable name according to Windows command line parsing rules
   while (auto c = *args) {
      if (c == L'\\')
         oddBackslash ^= 1;
      else if (c == L'"')
         quoted ^= !oddBackslash;
      else if (c == L' ' || c == L'\t')
         whitespace = !quoted;
      else if (whitespace)
         break;
      else
         oddBackslash = false;
      args++;
   }
   return QString::fromRawData(reinterpret_cast<const QChar*>(args), lstrlen(args));
}
```

Then:

```
QProcess process;
process.setNativeArguments(getWindowsCommandLineArguments());
```

#### Other Platforms

The equivalent to `setNativeArguments` is not available on other platforms, thus the best we can do is to pass the arguments via a `QString` roundtrip. This will work fine as long as the arguments are valid in the current 8-bit encoding. The arguments must be captured at the beginning of `main`, because Qt may remove the arguments it interprets itself:

```
QStringList &setProcessArguments() {
   static QStringList args;
   return args;
} 
const QStringList &processArguments() { return setProcessArguments(); }
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   setProcessArguments().reserve(argc-1);
   for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
      setProcessArguments().append(QString::fromLocal8Bit(argv[i]));

   QCoreApplication app{argc, argv}; // may modify argc, argv
   ...
}

QProcess process;
process.setArguments(processArguments());
```